# NativeWind will not work in my appliacation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I tried using NativeWind in my app, but I can't figure out why it's not working. I attempted to target my .js file, but it didn't work. I even deleted the node_modules and reinstalled them, but it didn't make any difference.
[image: here is the tilwind.config.js file]

[image: balbel.config.js]
[image: homescreen]
[image: App.js]
[image: path]
[image: dependecies]

Answer (score 1):

Add postcss.config.css

and paste it, then try again

```
    module.exports = {
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("nativewind/postcss")],
};

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        "nativewind/postcss": {
            output: "nativewind-output.js",
        },
    },
};
```

Then import output (js) file into App.js
like this -

```
import "./nativewind-output";
```

Hope it will work it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you missed post css file and missed to include css file